Multiple (locally) minimal surfaces of rotation given two points in the plane?
Given two points $(x_A,y_A)$ and $(x_B,y_B)$ in the plane we can find the curve that minimizes the surface of revolution (around the $x$ axis) as the function $y(x)$ that minimizes the functional $2\pi \int_{x_A}^{x_B}y\sqrt{1+y'^2} \mathrm dx$.
When applying Euler equations I can derive the known result $y = a \cosh(\frac{x-b}{a})$ and find $a,b$ by solving the following system for $a$ and $b$:
$$\begin{cases} y_A = a \cosh(\frac{x_A-b}{a}) \\y_B = a \cosh(\frac{x_B-b}{a}) \end{cases}$$
My reference book* says that depending on the relative position of the points, the solution may or may not be unique, or may not exist, then asks to discuss the cases.
I am aware that there are cases in which a continous solution cannot exist (typically if the two points are too spaced apart).
On the other hand how there can be multiple solutions for some cases? I would like an example to visualize this.
thanks
*Analytical Mechanics, an Introduction. Fasano, Marmi. 2006

Are you sure there isn't a factor of $a$ multiplying the $\cosh$?

@TedShifrin my bad, let me amend that. thanks!

OK, so now graph the function $\phi(t)=t\cosh(1/t)$ and you should see the answer to your non-existence and non-uniqueness questions. Indeed, you should see (numerically) that there will be precisely one instance of a unique solution!

As a follow-up to my previous comment, if you're interested, check out Exercise 16 on pp. 43-44 of my undergraduate differential geometry text, freely available here.

Here is an example of nonuniqueness of extrema passing through the points $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$. Both are extrema, but one is a mimimizer and one is a maximizer of the surface area of the surface of revolution.

